# Sybase Authentication Violation

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, sybase

I've been running into this error for the past 2 weeks on my Classic ASP application when connecting to sybase.

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Unable to connect to  database server: Authentication violation
```

I only get this error when I am attempting to insert records into the sybase database. The strange thing is that I get this error once every while; very inconsistent. I looked over the internet for a while and the only step I found was to authenticate the connection via the connection signature option:

```
SET TEMPORARY OPTION connection_authentication='company = company-name;
 application=application-name;
 signature=application-signature';
```

I changed the values as needed and I still receive the authentication violation error. I am certain it has to do with authorization because my application can read values from the sybase database without any errors, because unauthorized connections are in read only mode. I dont understand how my application can bypass the authorization frequently when writing records but will randomly stumble and get me this error. Am I missing anything? Are there other ways to authorize the connection?